# Add Google authentication method to existing ASP.NET WebAPI project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, google-oauth

I have existsing `C# ASP.NET WebAPI 2.0` project with a few methods for another **website**. This WebAPI project has no any authentication and returns `JSON` data. The first method takes two parameters from **website**: *Email* and *Password* then checks it in MS SQL table and returns `JSON` (**success** or **wrong**): if **success** then i create some **token** and add **token** with **user_id** to another MS SQL table. This method returns **token** if everything is ok.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/v1/auth/email-login")]
    [ActionName("EmailLogin")]
    public IHttpActionResult Postpipeline_EmailLogin([FromBody] PostAuthItem postAuthItem)
    {
        try
        {
            int? userId = db.USERS_GetUserId(postAuthItem.Email, postAuthItem.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            if (userId == null)
            {
                return Ok(new
                {
                    Error = "Wrong email or password!"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                string token = this.GetToken(40);

                db.TOKENS_Add(userId, token);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return Ok(new
                {
                    Token = token
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult(Request.CreateErrorResponse((HttpStatusCode)400, new HttpError("Http error! " + ex.Message + " " + ex.InnerException.Message)));
        }
    }
```

Now authorization via Google has been added to the **website**. So i need to add new method, that will check success or wrong authentication via Google. **Website** developer send me only *access_token* like this:

```
Request:
{
    "access_token": "ya47.Kdd_KeQ0mQiTzom20dQ6M83742KMYQpkCUqCZv0UbU2CjhMIuxIT5ugRXwIrOUcV-TGbUztMiRDRPzh0INrGgh7gqXyaIfyQAnNMmP0GhXRc6bbanEiPxV7fK9ss"
}
```

If there is possibility to check valid Google user with this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go directly though the Userinfo endpoint

```
GET /userinfo/v2/me HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer 29.GltcBsh3Q-qbIEslOBcifBKlRh2GfE0-P11tDMgBx_WdWdH1TG6iWkDtzj0e_zIERaDyq6b_oseOIiSpG3iO0LIeQuAAyn5VVDe50WVmdtWhrMiN27wTsUJY0jxP
```

This will return infomation about the user in question

```
{
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg", 
  "name": "Linda Lawton", 
  "family_name": "Lawton", 
  "locale": "en", 
  "gender": "female", 
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton", 
  "given_name": "Linda", 
  "id": "117200475532672775346"
}
```

Comment: Remember that you are only going to be able to get information back about a user if you had requested one of the profile scopes.   How are you authorizing this user?

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much, Linda!